# combining two custom .gtf files (r)

Tags: r, merge, bioconductor

I have two custom files and have been trying to combine them into a single .gtf file to eventually make a custom fasta for kallisto. 
i have been using the biostrings library (bioconductor)in R and have read both files in as Genomic Ranges

```
genes.gf <-readGFFAsGRanges("novel_genes.gtf")
isoforms.gf <-readGFFAsGRanges("novel_isoforms.gtf")
```

however, when i try to use cat to combine them, i get an error:

```
cat(genes.gf, isoforms.gf, file = "custom.gf")
```

Error in cat(tgenes.gf, isoforms.gf, file = "custom.gf") : 
  argument 1 (type 'S4') cannot be handled by 'cat'

rbind also doesn't seem to work:

```
rbind(genes.gf, isoforms.gf, file = "custom.gf")
```

giving this error:
Error in rbind2(argl[[i]], r) : no method for coercing this S4 class to a vector

I'm still very new to this and any advice/ suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I make two example gtf files:

```
library(rtracklayer)
gtf = import("ftp://ftp.ensembl.org/pub/release-99/gtf/saccharomyces_cerevisiae/Saccharomyces_cerevisiae.R64-1-1.99.gtf.gz")
export(gtf[gtf$gene_biotype=="protein_coding"],"coding.gtf")
export(gtf[gtf$gene_biotype=="tRNA"],"tRNA.gtf")
```

If it is a GRanges, you can combine them using c() :

```
g1 = import("coding.gtf")
g2 = import("tRNA.gtf")

export(c(g1,g2),"combined.gtf")
```

However, note the the above combined gtf is not sorted, and that if some columns appear in one but not the other, it will be filled with NAs.